# build a deep object with immutable js with for-loop

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I am trying to build an object using immutable-js to build the smaller objects that should then be merged into the larger object.

This is what I have tried:

```
let globalObject = Immutable.Map({});
let keys = ["a","b","c"];
let newKeys = ["x","y","z"];
const objThing = { "q": 77 };
let newGlobalObject = globalObject.setIn(keys, objThing);

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const original = newGlobalObject.getIn(['a', 'b']);
  const newKey = newKeys[i];
  const newObject = {};
  newObject[newKey] = i;
  const mergedObject = original.merge(newObject);
  globalObject = newGlobalObject.updateIn(['a', 'b'], val => {
    return mergedObject
  });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(globalObject));
```

However, the output is

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "q": 77
      },
      "z": 2
    }
  }
}
```

whereas I would like it to be:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "q": 77
      },
      "x": 0,
      "y": 1,
      "z": 2
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I found the answer.

I will not mark it as the answer to the question just yet since I want to give somebody else the chance to post a better answer... just because this works does not mean that it is correct ;)

I was creating a new variable called `newGlobalObject` to store the data since I thought that it would be wrong to just use the `globalObject` because that would be mutating things. But it turns out that it is exactly what I had to do.

```
let globalObject = Immutable.Map({});
let keys = ["a", "b", "c"];
let newKeys = ["x", "y", "z"];
const objThing = {
  "q": 77
};
globalObject = globalObject.setIn(keys, objThing);

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const original = globalObject.getIn(['a', 'b']);
  const newKey = newKeys[i];
  const newObject = {};
  newObject[newKey] = i;
  const mergedObject = original.merge(newObject);
  globalObject = globalObject.updateIn(['a', 'b'], val => {
    return mergedObject
  });
}

console.log(globalObject.toJs());
```

output: `{"a":{"b":{"c":{"q":77},"x":0,"y":1,"z":2}}}`